# How to change datetime field to work with it in other culture?

Tags: 2010, multilingual

I have a list with Datetime field.

I want change data content of the column to persian/english.

It is possible change the content when change language ?

Comment: hi there. you can change predefined content but there is no way to change the dynamic content of a list or any other thing to another language automatically. there is two obvious ways: 1.Use a Translator(in general not just sharepoint) 2.provide the necessary content manually. but if you just want to change the datetime field and again there is Two obvious ways: 1.Use a language pack 2.Develop or use a Custom Field.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can check these out that would help :) :

persian date/time

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17495/Persian-DateTime

CLR persian date/time

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28129/Creating-a-CLR-Persian-Date-Convertor-Function-for

Codeplex VS addon for date/time conversion between Georgian dates and Jalali dates

http://persiandate.codeplex.com/

changing date/time to culture

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590180/how-to-convert-a-datetime-string-to-a-current-culture-datetime-string

Comment: Thanks , but i want change content of list to other language.

Comment: Is it in english and you want to change the contents to persian or the other way round? sorry for some reason I thought it was to do with the dateTime

Comment: Yes, I want change the language of datetime field.

Comment: hi there. you can change predefined content but there is no way to change the dynamic content of a list or any other thing to another language automatically. there is two obvious ways: 1.Use a Translator(in general not just sharepoint) 2.provide the necessary content manually. but if you just want to change the datetime field and again there is Two obvious ways: 1.Use a language pack 2.Develop or use a Custom Field.